# How to reduce the number of colors in d3.scale.category10()?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

Consider the JSFIFDDLE link http://jsfiddle.net/userla/5D5eD/2/ . Here the number of colors should be limited to just two for each datapoint the d3.scale.category10() has 10 colors, it must be restricted to just 2. How to achieve this ?

```
var color = d3.scale.category10();
var g = main.append("svg:g");

   g.selectAll("scatter-dots")
 .data(data)
.enter().append("svg:circle")
.attr("cx", function (d, i) {
return x(d[0]);
  }) 
   .attr("cy", function (d) {
 return y(d[1]);
 }) 
 .attr("r", 5)
 .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d[0]);}) ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use, for example:

```
var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#1f77b4", "#ff7f0e"]);
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5D5eD/3/).

Comment: Thank you Anto Jurkovic.

Comment: Similarly, can we change the color of the line joining two data points ? the line color restricted to two colors ?

Comment: You mean here `.style("stroke", "steelblue")`? Or you have some other example?

Comment: Its in the same example http://jsfiddle.net/userla/5D5eD/2/. [2,2] to [3,3] should have one color of line [3,3] to [4,4] should have another color of line. The variation in the color of line should be just two.